# How to load different Layout pages based on domain name?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a .NET Core project where based on the subdomain I will load different Layout.cshtml pages.

Based on the subdomain a query should be done in the database which will return a code. Based on this code in my ViewStart.cshtml I will load the different layouts.

How can I get the subdomain? And where?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply add your own logic into your views or the global `_ViewStart.cshtml` that selects the correct layout depending on your own criterias. What I did in the past is add a `ViewData` property, so my `_ViewStart.cshtml` looks like this:

```
@{
  Layout = (string)ViewData["_OverwriteLayout"] ?? "_DefaultLayout";
}
```

So I just need to set the `ViewData["_OverwriteLayout"]` value somewhere inside the MVC pipeline. I personally did that within a [`ResultFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#result-filters), so that the logic does not run when non-view results are returned.

That could for example look like this:

```
public class CustomLayoutResultFilter : IAsyncResultFilter
{
    public Task OnResultExecutionAsync(ResultExecutingContext context, ResultExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (context.Result is ViewResult viewResult)
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Host.ToString() == "test.example.com")
                viewResult.ViewData["_OverwriteLayout"] = "_TestLayout";
        }

        return next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple Layout and can call them from their ViewStart.cshtml file.
Example if you have an second _Layout2.cshtml in a different folder from the other Layout then you create in this folder an _ViewStart.cshtml file with this path

```
@{
  Layout="~/Views/Shared/[your folder]_Layout2.cshtml"
 }
```

Comment: I know that, that's what I already have. But how to I get the subdomain, query the database and send the result to the ViewStart?

Comment: I would look into area path's

Comment: If this Layout have is related with an Index you call this from his controller.

Comment: I cannot do this for each controller. I want this:

User opens website -> website subdomain is read somewhere -> query db based on subdomain -> return value -> pass value to ViewStart. In Viewstart I already have a switch statement that loads the correct Layout